# Conditional formatting 2 different colors every two rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I want to apply conditional formatting to change the background color of alternating rows on a spread sheet. The rows will alternate between two colors (yellow and green) two lines each.

This is the code I am using:

```
=MOD(ROW(),2)*($A1<>"")
```

and

```
=(1-MOD(ROW(),2))*($A1<>"")
```

It changes every other line, but I want every two lines to be the same color. What do I need to change to make that work?

Answer (score 2):

to save some processor cycles, you can format whole range with the 1st color and use this formula to conditionally format 3rd and 4th row of every 4 rows:

```
=MOD(ROW()-1;4)>1
```

if you use this conditional format only to used range, e.g. by creating an Excel Table (the one without alternating row colors), there should not be need to include `$A1<>""`, but feel free to use it anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this (matches rows 1, 2, 5, 6, etc):

```
=MOD(FLOOR(ROW()/2+0.5,1),2)*($A1<>"")
```

and this (matches rows 3, 4, 7, 8, etc):

```
=MOD(FLOOR(ROW()/2-0.5,1),2)*($A1<>"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a pattern going on regardless of the cell value, I don't think a conditional formatting is necessary. You can just format one cycle of the chosen style (in that case, 2 cells) and use the format painter to apply it to the entire sheet. I know it's not as fun as programming cells, but if I got your question right,it should do the trick just fine.